# Real life usages for event.currentTarget?

Tags: jquery

*It is perfectly clear that  `event.target` deals with  the DOM element that initiated the event.

And - `event.delegateTarget` provides the  DOM element where we actually attached the listener ,*

But I'm having trouble to understand when would I use  - [*event.currentTarget*](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) :

Looking at jQuery samples which shows this example : [***JSBIN1***](http://jsbin.com/mupoc/2/edit)

It seems like it is the exact same as `event.delegateTarget`

```
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.currentTarget.nodeName );
});
```

[image]

Everywhere I click - it says : clicked "BODY" - which is exactly like the delegateTarget's behaviour

**Question**

In Which (real life) scenarios would I use `event.currentTarget`? *( example would be much appreciated)*

*nb  - couldn't find any currentTarget vs delegateTarget questions....*

Comment: With event delegation the difference becomes clear: http://jsbin.com/vanukumi/4/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event.target` and `event.currentTarget` are attributes of [`Event` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-interface-h2) defined by W3C spec:

- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target):

  > This property of event objects is the object the event was dispatched
  >   on. It is different than `event.currentTarget` when the event handler is
  >   called in bubbling or capturing phase of the event.
- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget):

  > Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses
  >   the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been
  >   attached to as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on
  >   which the event occurred.

Additionally, jQuery adds [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/):

> The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was attached

The difference with `event.currentTarget` is explained in

> This property is most often useful in delegated events attached by
>   `.delegate()` or `.on()`, where the event handler is attached at an
>   ancestor of the element being processed. It can be used, for example,
>   to identify and remove event handlers at the delegation point.
>
> For non-delegated event handlers attached directly to an element,
>   `event.delegateTarget` will always be equal to `event.currentTarget`.

For example, if you click the button in the following HTML:

```html
<div class="box">
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".box", function(e) {
    e.delegateTarget; // body
    e.currentTarget;  // .box
    e.target;         // button
});
```

Comment: Tnx   , This does'nt explain the difference between `event.delegateTarget and event.currentTarget`. this is pure quote from jq ( which I already read)

Comment: @RoyiNamir The quote explains it very well. I added an example.

Comment: Your edit made me understand :-) thank you. it's like the middle stage of bubbling

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTML markup as shown below

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com" data-ajax="true" data-id="345">
    <img src="company.jpg"/>
</a>
```

And you have bind handler to anchor

```
$("a").click(function(){
    // Some stuff
});
```

Now here in the click handler `event.target` points to the image but you have actually clicked on anchor and in the click handler you need to access the `data-id` attribute of anchor to perform some action. here to get the current target you can use `event.currentTarget` to access the anchor.

Comment: look at my demo. it contredict your answer.... I click on a child and it shows the top father( attached one)

Comment: I haven't tested, but this answer *feels* wrong. According to the MDN entry for [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget), it should always refer to the element to which the event was delegated.

Answer (score 0):

The event.currentTarget property is the element that is currently responding to the DOM event, which is the element you bound the event handler to. As for a real world usage? Not really sure.