# What is the purpose of Event.CurrentTarget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you talk about the purpose of use? Why is event.CurrentTarget used? I do not understand the [example here](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/). What does it do?

Comment: becose, you cant got n same elements in dom calling same method, and to know wich of all call method in current instance

Comment: If you assign a click handler to multiple elements, or if you do it dynamically, you might want to find out which element was actually clicked inside the handler. As explained you don't usually need it; but in case you bound `this` to another object, you can still get the one that was clicked / triggered / etc.

Comment: allows you to refer to the element where the event was based rather than, by say, its id or something else.

Comment: `event.currentTarget` on mouse last action of the element

Comment: Log the event object to console and inspect it. Will see it has a lot of different properties

Comment: It does exactly what it says it does, it's equal to the `this` value of the function, except in some cases, for instance where you specifically set a  `this` value with something like `$.proxy`, then `this` will be equal to whatever context you have provided, but `event.currentTarget` will still be the element, or whatever `this` would normally be.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352610/real-life-usages-for-event-currenttarget) might be an answer to your question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Hi, ı have reached your question limiT. Would you please give me a positive vote? I have questions to ask

Comment: dont understand what you want

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón My question is blocked. Would you vote positive if I ask?

Comment: your question is duplicated, and got link to original?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243462/alternate-to-imei   Would this be a question? @ÁlvaroTouzón